# What is pauman (is it stotra or method)

Tags: vedas

I have heard of [Pauman Abhishek](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB0QtwIwAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DCpDipi1Nbtw&ei=HCIHVY3OD5SWuATR84GIAQ&usg=AFQjCNGNZ70Sv47TRWJOlG3HPA4j9xFBcA&sig2=91bEWwM_igznzpPcdLMUTg&bvm=bv.88198703,d.c2E) like Rudra abhishek or Abhishek by Purusha Suktam. I don't know what is Pauman Strotra, like [Rudradyaya](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&sqi=2&ved=0CB0QtwIwAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DH4hLtzCeVds&ei=6yIHVbilFtCxuATf6oHwCw&usg=AFQjCNHlzz5ilXZOi43W_LVj2SssImc26g&sig2=LQjnWFGp7GyEv6I_nBwmdg&bvm=bv.88198703,d.c2E) from Rigveda, it's origins and any resource giving the mantra (samhita).

I am also confused about weather pauman could be used for abhishek of any god or godess.

[This](http://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_veda/pavamana.html?lang=sa) is pauman in *Sanskrit*

Comment: There is a section in Saama veda called Pavamana saamam. The first link which takes to the YouTube video is Sri Venkata subrabatham. I guess you mean to show what is abhishek with this link and no other connection to the question. In that case the second assumption is that since you said about Rudram which is part of a veda (Purusha suktam for one veda is not same for all), I mention Pavamana saamam, which is believed to remove all sins if chanted during Ekadesi days.